# Simple Bootlamp for a EV Bike

Tags: led, emc, emi-filtering

We are designing a simple 12V DC bootlamp (lamp to be installed in the boot) for an EV bike project.
(Vin : 12V DC)

Q1) Is the design OK? Any recommendations on it? 
Q2) Is EMI/EMC applicable to such a simple design? We are not using any PWM based driver/SMPS supply just 12V battery supply.
Q3) I need to add a reverse polarity protection in this circuit. Do I add an extra diode or do you think LED's will work (they are a diode in itself?

LED specs : 3 mm cool white, Vf = 3V, Imax = 50 mA

[image: 12V DC Boot Lamp Circuit]

Comment: Do you have a stable (contant) 12V? Or voltage changes as battery fluctuates (charges/discharges)?

Comment: It is a battery based supply so I am assuming it's a stable 12V DC.

Comment: What kind of battery is it (li-ion pack, lead)?

Comment: OK, so I just got an update, its a Li-Ion battery pack which will vary between 12V-15V DC.

Comment: Then I don't recommend a resistor solution as the brightness will change too much. Use a transistor current source and 3 Led in series. Btw, it is a 3 or 4 li-ion in series?

Comment: What if I add a 12.1V Zener in Input? Do you think that will help for a constant input?

Comment: It is too lossy, a current source has better efficiency.

Comment: What do you mean by "bootlamp" - white on the front or red on the back?  What are the forward voltage and current values for your LEDs?

Comment: Note that on some commercial E-bikes, the 12V lighting supply isn't directly off the battery.  The battery might be 36V, and the 12V supply comes from a switching regulator.  That will be very stable

Comment: @ChrisH I think "bootlamp" means "lamp on the boot" in British English, which would be "lamp on the trunk == rear lamp == red on the back" in American English.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact "bootlamp" means nothing at all in British English - that's what I speak.  As two words, "boot light"  would be a way of describing an internal white light to see inside the boot (/trunk) of a car, and still not applicable to any kind of bike.  My first thought was that it might indicate the microcontroller booting up - that's how far removed from normal or cycling use in British English it is.

Comment: @ChrisH My hunch still stands, until proven otherwise. I don't think it is *standard* British English (which you have now confirmed), but it is a logical derivative. Based on OP's name, I suspect (but could be wrong - profile doesn't say) that OP may be in a country with a British-related history (for lack of a better phrase) and countries separated for a while often end up with their own idioms.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact if you mean the OP might be using Indian English, say so, and I might even agree. Indian English is as far removed from British English as is American English, apart from spellings.

Comment: But anyway, we need clarification of the component specs even if not the terminology

Comment: @ChrisH That is what I *suspect*. But except anecdotally, I have absolutely no experience with Indian English as a variant, and for that matter OP's username sounds Indian to me *but* often people's names (assuming they are real or close to real, which itself is not always the case) do not necessarily indicate where they live or where/how they learned English.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact indeed, I wouldn't like to assume anything based on names. The rest of the post would be compatible with Indian English; it doesn't read like native British English. I've both visited India and had Indian colleagues in the UK, so have seen the linguistic differences first hand

Comment: @MichalPodmanický Would you mind turning your comments in an answer?

Answer (score 3):

It looks acceptable to me.

If the "12V" is reasonably stable I would consider using 3 LEDs in series
and getting more brightness for the energy consumed, or reducing the LED current to save energy.

As a purely DC circuit EMI and EMC is a non-issue so long as the 12V is not itself producing EMI

Comment: Thanks. Just as what I thought. Also, do I need to add a reverse polarity protection diode or do you think LED's will work?

Comment: OK, so I just got an update, its a Li-Ion battery pack which will vary between 12V-15V DC. Does that change any thing?

Comment: LED datasheets typically say that they are good for 5V reverse, so 10V for two in series,  some people say 20V, but I have damaged LEDs with 9V reverse. So if there's a risk of reverse connection a diode would be a good idea.  (or three in series instead of two in series is good for 15V reverse)

Comment: 12 to 15V .... two in series is probably best to get reasonably consistent brightness, or use a current regulator circuit.

Comment: What if I add a 12.1V Zener in Input? Do you think that will help for a constant input?

Comment: @MandeeshSingh not really, unless you want to waste most of your battery's power to make a Zener diode very hot.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer to both question depends on the specification of the LED that you plan to use. You may need to check the following:

1. What is the I-V characteristic curves? You can use these curves to figure out how much power the LED is consuming at the max supply voltage, and compare it to the max operating power recommended by spec sheet. LED current tend to grow exponentially with voltage, but the resistor should be able to suppress the current.
2. What is the maximum forward turn-on voltage of the LED? This will limit the number of LED you can have in series.
3. What is the reverse breakdown voltage of the LED? This will help you figure out if you need reverse polarity protection. To be on the safe side, the breakdown voltage of each LED should be larger than the max supply voltage. When one of the LED experienced avalanche breakdown due to a surge, all the voltage drop could fall between the other LED.